# ACORE API, assistance with errors and deployment

Tags: azerothcore

I'm having trouble with setting up ACORE API's and then having them work on a website.

Background:
Azerothcore running 3.3.5 on a debian standalone server, this has the Database, Core files and runs both the world and auth server basically a standard setup that is shown in the how-to wiki.

I also have a standalone web server, on the same subnet, but it's a separate server running linux and normal web server stuff, this has a wordpress installation with azerothcore plugin for user signup etc.
I'm trying to add the player map (https://github.com/azerothcore/playermap) and the ACORE-API set of functions (server status, arenastats, BG que and wow statistics) (https://github.com/azerothcore/acore-api)

Problem:
I understand the acore-api must be run in a container (docker or whatever) on the server, which I have done and it binds to port 3000, I can then go to the local ip:3000 and it brings up this error. (all db's etc are connecting and soap is working)
[error 404 when navigating to IP:3000](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWJgy.png)

I do get a few errors when running NPM install seen here: I'm not sure if they would be causing any issues or not.
[screenshot of NPM errors on install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W45KK.png)

But further that, when I put say 'serverstatus' on the webserver (separate server) and configure the config.ts file I can't seem to get anything to display.
I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but is the same scenario for all of the different functions for the acore-api

How are these meant to be installed and function? I feel I'm missing a vital step.

Likewise, with PLAYERMAP I have edited the comm_conf.php and set the realmd_id, but when loading the page, I do get the map, but the uptime is missing and no players are shown?

Could someone assist if possible?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like an issue with NodeJS version. Update your NodeJS to latest LTS version **16.13.0** (https://nodejs.org)

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply, I have the latest versions I believe now being NODE 17.0.1, NPM 8.1.3 but still can't seem to get it to work. 
[Nest] 159065  - 22/02/2022, 10:12:57 am     LOG [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
[Nest] 159065  - 22/02/2022, 10:12:57 am     LOG [InstanceLoader] AppModule dependencies initialized +134ms
[Nest] 159065  - 22/02/2022, 10:12:57 am     LOG [InstanceLoader] TypeOrmModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 159065  - 22/02/2022, 10:12:57 am   ERROR [ExceptionHandler] (0 , rxjs_1.lastValueFrom) is not a function

Comment: I have also just downgraded from 17.0.1 to 16.14.0 to see if it would make any difference, I still had NPM warnings about an unsupported engine and the command npm start fails to load still with the same error as the previous message above